# Scala: type inference of generic and it's type argument

Tags: scala, generics, variance

Lets assume I have instance of arbitrary one-argument generic class (I'll use `List` in demonstration but this can me any other generic).

I'd like to write generic function that can take instances (`c`) and be able to understand what generic class (`A`) and what type argument (`B`) produced the class (`C`) of that instance.

I've come up with something like this (body of the function is not really relevant but demonstrates that `C` conforms to `A[B]`):

```
def foo[C <: A[B], A[_], B](c: C) {
  val x: A[B] = c
}
```

... and it compiles if you invoke it like this:

```
foo[List[Int], List, Int](List.empty[Int])
```

... but compilation fails with error if I omit explicit type arguments and rely on inference:

```
foo(List.empty[Int])
```

The error I get is:

```
    Error:Error:line (125)inferred kinds of the type arguments (List[Int],List[Int],Nothing) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type C,type A,type B).
List[Int]'s type parameters do not match type A's expected parameters:
class List has one type parameter, but type A has one
  foo(List.empty[Int])
  ^
    Error:Error:line (125)type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: C
  foo(List.empty[Int])
                ^
```

As you can see Scala's type inference cannot infer the types correctly in this case (seems like it's guess is `List[Int]` instead of `List` for 2nd argument and `Nothing` instead of `Int` for 3rd).

I assume that type bounds for `foo` I've come up with are not precise/correct enough, so my question is how could I implement it, so Scala could infer arguments?

Note: if it helps, the assumption that all potential generics (`A`s) inherit/conform some common ancestor can be made. For example, that `A` can be any collection inherited from `Seq`.

Note: the example described in this question is synthetic and is a distilled part of the bigger problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to **hubertp** answer, you can fix you function by removing obsolete (in you example) type variable `C`, e.g:

```
def foo[A[_], B](c: A[B]) {
  val x: A[B] = c
}
```

In this case scalac would infer `A[_]` as `List` and `B` as `Int`.

**Update** (according to the comment).

If you need an evidence that `C` is subtype of `A[B]`, then use implicit:

```
def foo[A[_], B, C](c: C)(implicit ev: C <:< A[B]) = {
  val x: A[B] = c
}
```

Then it won't compile this:

```
scala> foo[List, String, List[Int]](List.empty[Int])
<console>:9: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< List[String].
              foo[List, String, List[Int]](List.empty[Int])
```

Comment: see my comment on hubertp answer

Comment: @EugenyLoy check my update, is it what you need? But scalac won't decompose C into A[_] and B, you can write to guys from typelevel scala fork, maybe they would implement it.

Comment: yes, this is closest to what I need. BTW, `=:=` suits better for my purposes than `<:<`, but I've got the idea and this is not that relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known limitation of current Scala's type inference for type constructors. Defining the type of formal parameter c as C only collects type constraints for C (and indirectly to A) but not B. In other words `List[Int] <: C => { List[Int] <: C <: Any, C <: A[_] <: Any }`.

There is a pretty simple translation that allows to guide type inference for such cases. In your case it is:

```
def foo[C[_] <: A[_], A[_], B](c: A[B]) { val x: A[B] = c }
```

Same semantics, just slightly different type signature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not actually solves the problem. I start with an argument of type `C` (which is I know to be a result of `A[B]`) and want to decompose it to the types it was built from (i.e. B and A). As @4lex1v pointed out in your example `C` is not really used at all and I need to be able to use all 3 types inside the function (i.e. body should be aware that argument is of type of `C` and conforms to `A[B]`)

Comment: Ah, yeah. In that case are you after something along the lines of the Unpack implicit hack mentioned in [ticket SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712)?